# Getting bold digits with XeLaTeX and mathspec

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, bold, mathspec

I'm trying to achieve something that I assumed was quite simple but it made me waste an insane amount of time so far.
I'm using XeLaTeX for a document and I'm setting “Arno Pro” as my font. I'm using the same font also for the math mode and I need a formula with bold digits.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[
Path = fonts/,Extension = .otf,
UprightFont=ArnoPro-Regular,
BoldFont=ArnoPro-Bold,
ItalicFont=ArnoPro-Italic,
BoldItalicFont=ArnoPro-BoldItalic,
Numbers={Proportional}
]{ArnoPro}

\setmathrm
[Path = fonts/,Extension = .otf,
UprightFont=ArnoPro-Regular,
BoldFont=ArnoPro-Bold,
ItalicFont=ArnoPro-Italic,
BoldItalicFont=ArnoPro-BoldItalic
]{ArnoPro}

\fontspec[Path=fonts/]{ArnoPro.otf}
\SetSymbolFont{Digits:m:n}{bold}{EU1}{\zf@family}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\boldsymbol{bf\ 0123}$\\
$\mathbf{bf\ 0123}$\\
$normal\ 0123$\\
$\mathit{it\ 0123}$\\
$\mathrm{rm\ 0123}$

\end{document}
```

Now, this works almost perfectly except that only text and symbols are affected, no digits.

I have tried all sorts of combinations, including some with `unicode-math`, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know about the LaTeX packages, but given that the Arno Pro is a text font, as opposed to math font, I would guess it does not have glyphs in the "Alphanumeric Mathematical Symbols"-block of the Unicode range which has the bold variants of the digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mathspec` is basically a collection of hacks; using a real Unicode Math font is better, if your document deals with mathematics.

However, here's a way to get bold digits:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){FreeSerif}

\setmathrm{FreeSerif}

\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\makeatletter
\SetSymbolFont{Digits:m:n}{bold}{EU1}{\eu@mathrm}{bx}{n}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mathbf{x}=\bm{0}+\bm{1}$

\end{document}
```

I've used FreeSerif as I don't have Arno Pro.

[image]

A full example using instructions with explicit paths for the fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[
  Path=/Library/Fonts/Kerkis-OTF/,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=Kerkis,
  ItalicFont=Kerkisitalics,
  BoldFont=Kerkisbold,
  BoldItalicFont=Kerkisbolditalic,
]{Kerkis}

\setmathrm[
  Path=/Library/Fonts/Kerkis-OTF/,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=Kerkis,
  ItalicFont=Kerkisitalics,
  BoldFont=Kerkisbold,
  BoldItalicFont=Kerkisbolditalic,
]{Kerkis}

\setmainfont[
  Path=/Library/Fonts/Kerkis-OTF/,
  Extension=.otf,
  Ligatures=TeX,
  UprightFont=Kerkis,
  ItalicFont=Kerkisitalics,
  BoldFont=Kerkisbold,
  BoldItalicFont=Kerkisbolditalic,
]{Kerkis}

\makeatletter
\SetSymbolFont{Digits:m:n}{bold}{EU1}{\eu@mathrm}{bx}{n}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Abc\textit{abc}\textit{\textbf{abc}}

$\mathbf{x}=\bm{0}+\bm{1}$

$\mathit{xyz}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! It works but apparently only with FreeSerif. As soon as I subsitute in my font it stops working. All I can see is this warning `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'EU1/ArnoPro(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using 'EU1/ArnoPro(0)/m/n' instead on input line 92.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'EU1/ArnoPro(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using 'EU1/ArnoPro(0)/m/n' instead on input line 92.`

Comment: I've tried to use `MinionPro` as well, same result, same warnings.

Comment: @adma You have to use `\setmainfont` instead of `\fontspec`, with similar options as for `\setmathsfont`.

Comment: I did, I took your example and substituted in `ArnoPro/MinionPro`. That's when I get the warnings about missing shapes. Probably I have to add some other `\SetSymbolFont` for them but I'm struggling to find anything about this command

Comment: @adma I don't know what to say; I added an example with full font declarations (using a font that's not in TeX Live) with which I get no warning.

Comment: yes your example is working, so thanks for that. I'll figure out the rest myself.